# Unable to upload new theme to wordpress from dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I installed wp to a server for the first time. The basic theme works and I can change the settings but I bought a new wordpress theme and was trying to upload it from the dashboard:

[image: upload theme]

But it gives me an error each time:

[image: Error]

These were suggestions I found online but didn't work: 
So I tried to change the permissions of all of the folders to 755. And then I changed the permissions of the file update.php to 755 also but I still get the same error. I also tried editing the .htaccess of the folder 'AALimo' (folder which contains the wp dir) but that didn't work either. I'm not sure if I edited the .htaccess properly.

Comment: try to delete all your .htaccess files and let wp generate them anew. Also, make sure zou DO have a "wp-content/themes" folder on your server . lastly you can try to download a fresh copy of wp and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just manually uploaded the theme into the theme directory using ftp instead of the theme uploader from dashboard and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using C-Panel. I had to upload zip file in WordPress theme folder in public html. extract the zip file and you can install it easily .